# how to format entire MacBook Pro (flash kernel + ram + disk ....)

Tags: macos, privacy, disk-format

I want to format everything. Is it possible without opening the device ? It's a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports) running Ventura 13.3.1 (a) (22E772610a)

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, are you selling it, or just wanting a 'clean slate', or something else? Note that for most purposes, you can just Erase All Content and Settings in System Settings > General. There's no point in erasing the OS if you're just going to put it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Booting to recovery and then following Apple's procedure for erase and install will format everything. Firmware, software, disk.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/erase-and-reinstall-macos-mh27903/mac

You also should review the steps on how to prepare a Mac for donation or sale. Some services and auxiliary security features are not in the OS and reside in the Secure Enclave and on servers Apple and cellular companies control.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065

In some limited cases you could wipe the drive without opening the Mac, but most people need it to be open and running to ensure everything is reset properly. Count on that unless you have a limited, special case on your hands - with that Mac - it's almost certain you want to clear the non-OS items to be thorough.